# Different types for stddev_pop() and avg() aggregate functions

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame that contains a column of type  decimal(38,8), and I perform some operation on it to calculate the standard deviation and the average of this column.

Here is the schema and the content of the dataframe

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- count: decimal(38,4) (nullable = false)
```

| key | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 2.0000 |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 10.0000 |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 2.0000 |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 4.0000 |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 2.0000 |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 2.0000 |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 10.0000 |

When I operate the following operation

```
df.groupBy(col("key")).agg(stddev_pop("count").as("std dev"), avg("count").as("average"))
```

The resulting schema is

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- std dev: double (nullable = true)
 |-- average: decimal(38,8) (nullable = true)
```

which results in different formating (different number of decimals) for the std dev and average columns

| key | std dev | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik | 3.499271061118826 | 4.57142900 |

My questions: Why the output of stddev_pop() and avg() have different types?
Should I cast one of the two colums (for example std dev to be of type decimal(38,4)) to have the same formatting, or is there another way of formatting double values ?

Here is a simplified example that reproduce this behavior:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(
     Seq(
     StructField("key", StringType, nullable = false),
     StructField("count", DecimalType(38,4), nullable = false)
     )
     )

val data = Seq(
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(2.0)),
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(10.0)),
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(2.0)),
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(4.0)),
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(2.0)),
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(2.0)),
     Row("2_AN8068571086_EPA_EUR_PID1742804_ik", BigDecimal(10.0))
     )
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
 
df.printSchema()
df.show(false)

val df1 = df.groupBy(col("key")).agg(stddev_pop("count").as("std dev"), avg("count").as("average"))

df1.printSchema()
df1.show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that average of decimal can be represented as decimal that's why decimal is used for avg, while stddev is by definition real number that's why double is used. I wouldn't cast double to decimal as it's kinda strange, the other direction, casting avg to double seems to be more reasonable but it really depends on the semantics of you columns